# How to use SQLite on libgdx (only core and project)?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, libgdx

I need to use a database to save the score of the player using SQLite. I only have core and android project. I know that I need to implement an interface in core and use the SQLite in the Android project, but i don't understand what more can I do.

In **android project**, the database using SQLite:

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements DataBaseInterface{

// Versión de la base de datos
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Nombre de la base de datos
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gamescore";

// Nombre de la tabla
private static final String TABLE_SCORE = "score";

// Nombres de cada columna de la tabla
private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_SCORE = "score_value";

public DataBase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creación de las tablas
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_SCORE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORE + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_SCORE + " TEXT" + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_SCORE_TABLE);

}

// Actualización de la base de datos
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // La BD anterior es eliminada en caso de existir
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SCORE);

    // Se vuelve a crear la BD
    onCreate(db);
}

// Para añadir una nueva puntuación obtenida por el jugador
public void addScore(int score) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    //Valor de la puntuación
    values.put(KEY_SCORE, score);

    // Inserción de valores
    db.insert(TABLE_SCORE, null, values);

    // Se cierra la conexión con la BD
    db.close();

}

// Obtención de todas las puntuaciones
public String[] getAllScores() {

    // Query que selecciona todos los datos de la tabla
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORE;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    int i = 0;

    String[] data = new String[cursor.getCount()];

    //Se van añadiendo los datos hasta que se recorra entero
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        data[i] = cursor.getString(1);

        i = i++;

    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // Se devuelven los datos obtenidos
    return data;
}}
```

In **core** project, the interface:

```
public interface DataBaseInterface {
public void addScore(int score);
public String[] getAllScores();}
```

I read this guide:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

But i don't know how to do that with SQLite, I guess it's something simple but I'm a noobie.

Answer (score 1):

Try [gdx-sqlite](https://github.com/mrafayaleem/gdx-sqlite), a cross-platform LibGDX extension for `SQLite` database handling.

This project is no more actively maintained so check out the various [forks](https://github.com/mrafayaleem/gdx-sqlite/network) here to follow up with active developments around this repository.

Currently supported platforms:

- Android (Implemented using Android `SQLite` API)
- Desktop (SQLite JDBC from https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/wiki/Home)

Comment: Thanks! I check it out. But it is possible to use sqlite without this extension, right?

Comment: Currently `Interfacing` is the only solution in my mind and above extension is nothing more than interfacing with different platform(currently only for 2), you can check Android implementation of this library for your requirement